# matplotlib/python: how to have an area with no values

Tags: python, matplotlib

My client is requesting that a line chart extends with values up to a certain x axis, and then leaves 1 xtick with no values (empty)

I managed to add the emty x space, but the values still show, I-d need the lines to disappear "after Jul 13", the same way the fill stops....

[image: current status of chart]

Here's my code so far:

```
 for i, val in enumerate(data):  
        #data is an array with 3 elements, every elem has an array of y values in y[]
        linecolor = colors[i]
        # y is a 2D array of values: [[1,2,3,4,5,0],[1,2,3,4,5,0],[1,2,3,4,5,0]]
        ax.plot(x, y[i], '.-', label=doctor_names[i], markersize=8,fillstyle='full',linewidth=1.5, color=linecolor, clip_on=True, zorder=30)
        ax.fill_between(x, 0, y[i], where=[True, True, True, True, True, False], color=WeeklyReviewChart.fillcolors[i], alpha=0.8, edgecolor="white", zorder=20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to get matplotlib to not draw a value, set it to `np.nan`.
This is useful for drawing a line break due to a vertical asymptote, for example.

However, if the part of a plot that you do wish to leave empty occurs entirely along a left or right margin, then all you really need to do is call `ax.set_xlim` to expand the region to be drawn:

```
ax.set_xlim(min(x), max(x)+DT.timedelta(days=7))
```

---

For example,

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2015)

x = [DT.date(2015,6,15)+DT.timedelta(days=i*7)
     for i in range(5)]
y = np.random.randint(25, size=(3,5)).astype(float)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
color = ['blue', 'green', 'red']
for i in range(3):
    ax.plot(x, y[i], '.-', markersize=8, fillstyle='full', linewidth=1.5, 
            clip_on=True, zorder=30)

    ax.fill_between(x, 0, y[i], alpha=0.5, color=color[i], 
                    edgecolor="white", zorder=20)
ax.set_xlim(min(x), max(x)+DT.timedelta(days=7))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that actually "shrinks" the whole chart to the visible part, that is the empty part disappears

Comment: hey, what I also had missing is `ax.set_xlim(min(x), max(x))` ! Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, on second thought, all you really need is `ax.set_xlim` -- no setting values to `NaN` required.